# Why am I getting this 'can't modify frozen hash' error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Person model & an Item model. A person has many items, and an item belongs to a person.

In this code, I need to delete the existing items for a person, and create new ones from a parameter (which is an array of hashes). Then, I need to update one of the item's fields, based on one of its other fields.

```
@person = Person.find(params["id"])

@person.person_items.each do |q|
    q.destroy
end

person_items_from_param = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params["person_items"])

person_items_from_param.each do |pi|
    @person.person_items.create(pi) if pi.is_a?(Hash)
end

@person.person_items.each do |x|
    if x.item_type == "Type1"
        x.item_amount = "5"
    elsif x.item_type == "Type2"
        x.item_amount = "10"
    end
    x.save
end
```

On the `x.item_amount = "5"` & `x.item_amount = "10"` lines I get this error:

```
RuntimeError in PersonsController#submit_items
can't modify frozen hash
```

How can I fix this? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suspect

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params["person_items"])
```

returns a frozen hash which you then use to create objects

```
@person.person_items.create(pi) if pi.is_a?(Hash)
```

And since its frozen you can't modify it.

You could

A
Make a deep copy of the JSON object

or

B
Reload the model instance which should reinstantiate the object making the fields unfrozen.

Option A is the "better" solution but difficult because the only way I know of deep copying is serializing and deserializing and object in place and assigning the return value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I understand though, I'm not trying to modify the hash/JSON object, I'm trying to modify the ActiveRecord object that I just created. This may have been a little confusing in my code, I've changed some of the variable names to try to make it clearer.

Comment: I believe ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params["person_items"]) creates the frozen hash. but when you reload it ActiveRecord will just instantiate a new hash that isn't frozen

Comment: reload works when tried to delete parent after deleting child

Answer (score 6):

If you use q.destroy before saving element then you will get the error. better save the element first and then use destroy.

Answer (score 2):

You can get around this if you read the person_items from the database again rather than using the association.  The association is stale and pointing to the destroyed rows.

Instead of 
`@person.person_items.each do |x|`

Try
`PersonItem.where(:person_id=>@person.id).each do |x|`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a deep copy of any object in rails includes JSON, so just do it.
 Remember that `clone` preserves the frozen state, while `dup` doesn't.

Easiest way to fix error `can't modify frozen Array` is to `dup` this frozen array ;)

```
person_items_from_param = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params["person_items"]).dup
```